# Variable-size data type for numbers in Oracle

Tags: database, oracle, sqldatatypes, varchar2

So the advantage of using VARCHAR2 over VARCHAR is mainly that VARCHAR2 occupies variable size space in database depending on its length; this comes especially efficient when the column value inserted is null because virtually no space is occupied in this case. So by the same token, is there a data type for numbers that behaves in the same way so that when the number inserted is null no space is wasted in db?

Comment: `VARCHAR2` and `VARCHAR` are absolutely identical, there is no difference. Are you maybe referring to the difference of `VARCHAR2` vs. `CHAR`?

Comment: "Space is cheap" not; if you're nearing the end of the amount of space you can add to the box dropping unused tables and rebuilding tables etc will save you far more than playing around with numeric datatypes.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name correct me if I'm wroing, but I think VARCHAR2 and VARCHAR are different, though they used to be the same.

Comment: @Ben that's a valid point, thanks!

Comment: @JasonYe: no they are (still) the same. From the manual: "*Although the VARCHAR datatype is currently synonymous with VARCHAR2*": http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements001.htm#i45694

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: not sure if that's absolutely the case as I'm no expert myself, but that manual could be outdated. As far as I know, varchar will occupy space for NULL values whereas varchar2 will not. thanks for the prompt reply though:)

Comment: @JasonYe: Those two datatypes are **identical**. If you define a column with `varchar` it will be created as `varchar2`. Try it.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Just tried it, you're right! Varchar(10) became Varchar2(10), looks like they are total synonyms...thanks

Answer (score 4):

Yes, variable-length number data type exists,  it's called [NUMBER](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements001.htm#sthref118).

Oracle stores the precision (significant digits) and the scale separately, using the minimum space needed for precision (scale takes a single byte).

NUMBER(x,y) are a subtype of NUMBER, they are stored physically in the same way as regular NUMBER, they just have extra constraints.

AFAIK, there is no equivalent of CHAR for numbers.

You can see how Oracle stores data internally with the [DUMP](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions055.htm#i77278) function:

```
SQL> select dump(1), dump(12345), dump(123456789) from dual;

DUMP(1)            DUMP(12345)              DUMP(123456789)
------------------ ------------------------ ------------------------------
Typ=2 Len=2: 193,2 Typ=2 Len=4: 195,2,24,46 Typ=2 Len=6: 197,2,24,46,68,90
```

As you can see the data length increases with precision.

Comment: That partially solves the problem, but here's a thought, if I have a nullable column A of type NUMBER in table T, then for any record in Table T that has null in column A, does the database somehow still allocate space to that column as a quasi place holder?

Comment: NULL numbers will take one byte per column before the last column that has a value. The last trailing NULL columns are not stored and take 0 byte.